# Is there a function in Python to find the diff between two dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, diff

I'm looking to find the diff between two dictionaries.

```
[Dict. 1]
{"1":"w"},
{"2":"x"},
{"3":"y"}

[Dict. 2]
{"2":"b"},
{"3":"y"},
{"4":"z"}
```

I want to find the diff that will transform Dict. 2 into a dictionary that is identical to Dict. 1

I am not allowed to set Dict. 2 equal to Dict. 1.

I can only modify Dict. 2 by using the least number of add/update/remove actions possible.
For the above example, my diff should look like.

```
[Dict. 2]      [Diff]              [Dict. 2]
{"2":"b"},     add("1","w")        {"1":"w"},
{"3":"y"},  +  update("2","x")  =  {"2":"x"},
{"4":"z"}      remove("4")         {"3":"y"}
```

Using Python, how can I find the diff for these two dictionaries? My diff needs to contain the least number adds, updates, and removes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
If you search in your browser for "Find list differences", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney While it solves part of my problem, the difference it creates does not retain enough information on its own to help me create the diff I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could try working with set differences:

```py
def transform_dicts(a, b):
    extra = set(dict_2.items()) - set(dict_1.items())
    missing = set(dict_1.items()) - set(dict_2.items())

    for key, val in extra:
        del b[key]

    for key, val in missing:
        b[key] = val

    return b
```

It's not particularly terse but it will take few operations to complete.